# I want to find-and-replace a sentence, while keeping several segments

Tags: notepad++, replace

Is there a way in Notepad++ to retain on or more entire strings, and place them somewhere else?

To Clarify, what I want to do is search for a sentence such as

```
QuestionAnswers[qnumber 35]="Fruit", "Plants"
```

and replace with

```
NewFormatQuestion = [FirstAnswer="Fruit", SecondAnswer="Plants"]
```

This isn't the actual code, but it represents what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you know regular expressions, you can use the regex setting in the find and replace tool to do what you want (I think). I don't know regex so I can't help on that front.

Comment: Allow me to elaborate.

Due to the character limit, I've posted exactly what my problem is here: http://shorttext.com/fxpnjwu0p7